# Firebase - Retrieving a single object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry for the long question. I have a list of events which I get like this:

```
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  events: FirebaseListObservable<EventModel[]>;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.events = db.list('/events');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Events are displayed like this:

```
<md-card *ngFor="let event of events | async">
    <a [routerLink]="['event', event.slug]"><img class="event-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30" />{{ event.name }}</a>
</md-card>
```

The `event.component` looks like this:

```
export class EventComponent implements OnInit {

  event: Object;
  name: String;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase, route: Router) {

    const eventQuery = db.list('/events', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'slug',
        equalTo: 'event-name'
      }
    }).subscribe(data => {
      this.event = data[0];
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`this.event` is complete and the correct information is being queried. It looks like this:

```
Object {category: "category", description: "description", googleMap: "map", guests: Object, name: "Event name"…}
category: "category"
description: "description"
googleMap: "map"
guests: Object
name: "Event name"
slug: "event-name"
venue: "The venue"
$exists: function ()
$key: "-xxxxxxxx"
__proto__: Object
```

When I try to display the name `{{event.name}}` I get an error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]
```

Additional question:

Since the event information already exists in `HomePageComponent`, can it be sent to `EventComponent` and used to display the event? Maybe this will avoid an additional database query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use safe operator **`?`**

```
<md-card *ngFor="let event of events | async">
    <a [routerLink]="['event', event?.slug]"><img class="event-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/30/30" />{{ event?.name }}</a>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. I added the safe operator to the `event.component.html` and it worked. I don't have any errors in the `homepage.component.html` where the link is. So that works. Did you notice my additional question?